# Django - Using month from datetime in model filter

Tags: django, datefield

I have a model called Watch with a datefield called date and I want to only show the objects from that model that have the same month as the current month. I tried:

```
Watch.objects.filter(date.month=now.month).order_by('-day')
```

But this appeared not to be possible. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Watch.objects.filter(date__month=now.month).order_by('-day')
```

Have a look at the [QuerySet API Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference)